# Google Analytics track pageview automatically add slash to url

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've been using Google analytics trackPageview for a while and recently used the following js function to track some form submit button, which is to grab the current url and add some parameters to it. Things work fine, except that the URL that I see in the report is /https://www.mysite.com?pg=confirm (with a forward slash at front), instead of https://www.www.mysite.com?pg=confirm as I wanted. How to remove that slash? Thanks!

```
function trackGoogle(btn){  
  var curl = document.URL;
  var confirm_url;
  if (btn == 1){
    confirm_url = curl + '?pg=confirm';}
  else {confirm_url = curl + '?pg=confirm';}
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', confirm_url]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a filter to include the hostname with URL paths, or even any other filters on the profile/view?

Answer (score 1):

Analytics generates your pageview reports relative to the site's root for the property/profile you're viewing. The `confirm_url` parameter you're passing to GA is assumed to be the relative path (excluding the domain) from the site's root. In other words, the preceding slash stands for "www.mysite.com" and so `confirm_url` should be "?pg=confirm"

Comment: I think I still need to get the folder/path and file name dynamically, so the virtual page would be /folder1/folder2/file1?pg=confirm

Comment: I think window.location.pathname instead of document.url will do the trick. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Yeah I see the problem. You want to pull in the relative path, not the absolute path for the URL parameter confirm_url